# What shooter is Miles playing in the beginning of Guns Akimbo movie?

Tags: game-identification

In the beginning of [Guns Akimbo](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6902676/) Miles is playing some FPS with soldiers shooting some kind of werewolves:

[image: FPS-with-werewolves-1]
[image: FPS-with-werewolves-2]

What is this game?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That is [Metro 2033 Redux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_2033_(video_game)) by the looks of it.  I think that is the level where you start heading towards the tower in chapter 7.  Here is a [video](https://youtu.be/XhFyBzkLBE4?t=17) of said level, to which the opening scene appears to be what the movie shows.

Other give aways:

- The monsters they are fighting (Nosalises)
- The watch on the characters wrist

Comment: wow, that was fast! Checked the video - it also has that metal fence thing.

Comment: @arghtype I noticed the fence thing too, but didn't know how to describe it.  It's a great game if you haven't played it.  Would recommend it!